# How to repeat a pattern of cells that are filled with data from different columns of a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

From `Image 1`, I would like to spread the data in each column out into the pattern in `Image 2`.

Image 1:

[image: Image 1]

Image 2:

[image: Image 2]

This is simple enough to do manually but is time-consuming. I am wondering if there is a way to autofill the data by referencing the date cell or the column and having the pattern auto-fill depending on what date/column is entered.

I am only new to Excel, but I believe there is a simple way to do this that I am unsure of.

Comment: Welcome to [su]. How new are you to Excel? Do you already know how to use formulas?

Comment: Yeah your probably can do it with some type of 2D index/match formula, but you need to make sure your equipment names are exactly the same in the two tables. It seems easier to just hide/unhide columns for the date range you want...